# Dealing with a site that uses a DWT file and its indicies

Tags: html, dreamweaver, dwt

I am having a slight issue with a site I am in charge of updating.

The creator of the site used a Dreamweaver template as its base, and has about 10 of its html files with the DWT code inside of it.

I'm not big on Dreamweaver anymore, and could rewrite it without the DWT but it needs to go out today so that isn't an option atm.

I can edit the template easily in Dreamweaver, however the bodies of the html files are not editable.

From what I have picked up is that if you edit the DWT file, all of the sub files that it references should update.

However, this is not the case with this site.

The body of a lot of the sub html files includes tags like:

```
 <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="head" --><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```

etc...

Is there a way to update these files manually, or is there a trick to editing the DWT files and having all of the files that it points to update?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your menu:
`Modify > Library > Update Pages...`

From there you should be able to select your entire site (all pages that use the template you're currently editing).

DW will then iterate through all pages that have been built with said template, and rewrite the HTML inside those files.

From my experience with DW, you're better off to migrate all your files away from it... :-)
Messing with the templates is fine, but modifying a page that uses a template (outside of DW) will hose that page, and it can get ugly quick -- really quick. And there's not much recourse once the ugly has come to the party.

Good luck